# Corpus file format for Moses

Tags: linux, moses

I'm using Moses to make a Language model.

I followed the instructions from this link: [Baseline System: Moses](http://www.statmt.org/wmt11/baseline.html)

I have google 1-gram file that looks like:

```
</S>    95119665584
<S>     95119665584
,       30578667846
.       22077031422
<UNK>   21594821357
the     19401194714
-       16337125274
of      12765289150
and     12522922536
```

That means that the word "of" appeared 12,765,289,150 times.

Now I want to make a Language Model from this file ("Build Language Model"),

I don't know if this file format will work with Moses.

In the tutorial they are working with "europarl-v6.en", but I can't find it on the web to check the file format.

## LAST EDIT:

I need to represent each letter as word, so "hello" becomes "h e l l o".

After representing each word as I said , which format should I use?

Should it be:

```
o f
o f
o f
a n d
a n d
```

Or like the original format:

```
o f       12765289150
a n d     12522922536
```

Or maybe in other format ?

Does it still count as google n-gram ?

I followed the link: [How can I use the Google Web N-gram corpus to build an LM](http://www-speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/srilm-faq.7.html) as @
MukundKRoy suggested, but I don't know how to use it in my case (1-gram,2-gram...my new file isn't const).

I'll be glad if someone can tell me what format should this file be to use it with SRILM as simple as I can.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SRILM is taking care of the 1-2-3..-grams, don't bother.

I've done something similar, take a look over here:

[Moses Installation and Training Run-Through](http://www.statmt.org/moses_steps.html)

In `PART II - Build a Model` , section `Build Language Model` , it is working perfect with google n-grams.

Let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CMU-Cambridge Statistical Language Modeling Toolkit` to build your language model. Refer `wfreq2vocab` and `text2wngram`. I think this format of LM will work fine with moses.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use Moses, do you know what is the format of the file?

Comment: Moses can use both SRILM and IRSTLM and I use SRILM. Since you have only unigram data so there will be no backoff weight.So as per SRILM format you need to have "probability" "unigram" and third column blank. Have a try on this...

Comment: I;m using SRILM too, please look at my fist edited post. Do you know witch format SRILM working with ?

Comment: If you are using SRILM, then go for the process mentioned at http://www-speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/srilm-faq.7.html  Section B6. Try it and tell me.